# tcsh grep trouble

Tags: freebsd, tcsh

I use FreeBSD

```
> uname -sr
FreeBSD 6.3-RELEASE
```

When I query

```
> grep `whoami` /etc/passwd
```

It shows me the information I want:

[image]

But when I try getting it in a tcsh script:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set login = `whoami`
echo $login

set query = `grep $login /etc/passwd`
echo $query
```

it brings me the following:

```
dolg_gr
echo: No match.
```

Why 'No match' ?
How can I get the string it provides me at the command shell in the $query variable?

Comment: Can't you just use ``getent passwd `whoami` ``?

Comment: [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda), unfortunately, I'm told to get the string from /etc/passwd file.. I have to get it inside a variable from that file exactly.

Comment: Are you aware that version 6.x was end-of-life over 10 years ago and we will be on version 13 any day now?

Comment: It's all I've got, [Rob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3887/rob).

Comment: `getent passwd` _would_ get it from the `/etc/passwd` file.  It's safer as your `grep` would pick out irrelevant entries if your username was something like `roo` or `nolo`.

Comment: Isn't it simply because your unquoted variable expansion `$query` in (`echo $query`) is subject to globbing (and contains `*`)? The `no match` isn't coming from `grep`.

Comment: Bravo, [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver)! Indeed, `echo "$query"` outputs the string. Please write the answer.

Comment: @Григорий thanks - I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `grep` - it's a problem with the unquoted variable expansion in

```
echo $query
```

and the fact that the matched line returned by `grep` contains the globbing character `*`. In `tcsh`, the default behavior for unsuccessful globs is similar to bash's `failglob` option - the error is telling you that there is no *filename match* for your passwd string:

```
$ tcsh -c 'echo dol_gr:*:3291'
echo: No match.
```

[As mentioned by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636825/tcsh-grep-trouble/636844?noredirect=1#comment1193187_636844), the right way to quote variable expansions in (t)csh is to use the `q` modifier. Also note that `tcsh`'s `` `...` `` splits on SPC, TAB and NL when unquoted and on NL only when quoted:

```
set query = "`grep $login:q /etc/passwd`"
echo $query:q
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in general, it should be `echo $query:q`. `echo "$query"` won't work for values of `$query` that contain newline characters. `echo "$query:q"` won't work if it contains backslash followed by newline (and avoid `echo` for the usual reasons). But maybe the better advise here would be to stay away from (t)csh.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas - answer updated

Comment: (for the record, that `$login:q` is not guaranteed to quote properly when inside those quoted backticks. See for instance: `a=$'a\\\nb c' tcsh -c 'printf "<%s>\n" "\`printf %s\\n $a:q\`"'` which removes the backslash and splits into `a`, `b` and `c`. I don't even know if it's possible to get it right here and have given up on tcsh for this kind of reason over 25 years ago).